# How to prove that every algebraically closed integral domain is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Suppose $R$ is an integral domain and $R$ is algebraically closed. Prove that it then follows $R$ is a field.

Comment: Let $a$ be a non-zero element of your ring $R$. Then the polynomial $ax-1$ has a root in $R$...

Comment: @Mariano: Do we need to use the fact that there are no zero divisors?

Comment: If for every $a\in R\setminus 0$ the polynomial there exists a $b\in R$ such that $ab=1$, then there are no divisors of zero. (I am assuming the ring is commutative...)

Comment: @Mariano, how about turning these comments into an answer?

Answer (score 3):

*This is a community wiki answer intended to get this question off the unanswered list.*

---

As Mariano mentions in the comments, the solution of $ax-1$ for $a\neq 0$ furnishes an inverse for $a$ in $R$.